# What was a draco?

Tags: classical-latin, meaning, animals

The Latin dictionaries I checked suggest that the word *draco* is attested in classical literature and it is often translated as "dragon".
However, it is my impression — which may well be wrong! — that the current dragon imagery in popular culture comes mainly from China or that region of Asia more broadly.
Therefore I suspect that my intuitive image of a dragon might be far from what the Romans meant by a *draco*.

So, what was a *draco*?
Could it be just any snake or serpent, or did it refer to something more specific?
Have we identified a species that the Romans would call *draco*?
Was it a real thing or something more mystical?
Are there illustrations of what a *draco* is?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The word dragon is far older than the Medieval dragon or the West's knowledge of the Chinese dragon. In fact, it's no coincidence, either, that *dragon* is derived from *draco*. It's the meaning of the former which has changed, so as an archaicism, *dragon* is still a fine translation.

As to what the Greeks and Romans thought of *draco* (and *δράκων*), these would be simply "large snakes." In Greek mythology, *δράκοντες* were large enough to be enemies to heroes and gods: Cadmus slew the [Ismenian dragon](http://www.theoi.com/Ther/DrakonIsmenios.html), which you can see represented on a vase here:

[image: Cadmus battles the Ismenian Dragon]

This really is just some monstrous snake, and is likely what ordinary people thought of when they heard the word.

However, they could also be true monstrosities, having [multiple heads](http://www.theoi.com/Ther/DrakonHesperios.html) or being [underwater nightmares](http://www.theoi.com/Ther/KetosAithiopios.html).

In some places, like *Odyssey* 12.202, it's just a regular snake, and Lewis & Short list a number of pet *dracontes*:

> I. Prop. (those of the tame sort, esp. the Epidaurian, being kept as pets by luxurious Romans), Cic. Div. 2, 30; 66; Plin. 8, 17, 22, § 61; 29, 4, 20, § 67; Suet. Aug. 94; “Sen. de Ira, 2, 31

In short, when you see *draco*, think snake first, but allow for the possibility of some monstrous snake as well.