# request for translation from Latin to English

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I saw following text on the back of a T-shirt:

> Crux sacra sit mihi lux
> Non draco sit mihi dux
> Vade retro Satana,
> Numquam suade mihi vana
> Sunt mala quae libas,
> Ipse venena bibas

Image of the print:

[image]

I just met a guy with a shirt with this text on it's back. There was also a St. Benedict's Cross on the front with some words but I haven't captured it.

Could anyone translate for me this text, please?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you provide some context behind this text as well as anything that you've tried?

Comment: Well, I just met a guy with a shirt with this text on it's back. There was also a St. Benedict's Cross on the front with some words but I haven't captured it. Unfortunately all I possibly imagine was to use those OCR scanners but I saw it couldn't recognize letters correctly and in addition with google translator the text I've received was this: Holy Cross be my light
 The dragon will not be my guide
 GET THEE BEHIND ME, SATAN,
 JUMQUAM suggest to me PHANTOM
 There are evils which burn
 Sharp drink poison...

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Benedict_Medal

Answer (score 6):

Those words are a [Christian formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vade_retro_satana) closely associated with St. Benedict and the Benedictine order. It is meant to fend off the devil and his temptations, and the translation is as follows:

> May the holy cross be my light
> May not the serpent be my guide
> Move back, Satan,
> Never promote your vanities to me
> What you pour out is evil,
> Drink your poison yourself.

Notes:

1. It seems that *draco* is usually translated ad “dragon.” I preferred “serpent” in this context. Both words are used in conjunction with the devil in Christian literature.
2. The central line and arguably the title of the blessing is: *Vade retro Satana*. This is certainly an allusion to Jesus' words in the Gospel of Mark 8:33, where he says: *Vade retro me Satana*: Get thee behind me, Satan.

The initials of all the words of this blessing are arranged on the reverse side of the [St. Benedict Medal](https://www.romancatholicman.com/st-benedict-medal-with-exorcism-blessing/) in a pattern nicely described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Benedict_Medal#The_medal%E2%80%99s_symbolism). The oldest evidence of this text appears to be a manuscript from 1414 found at the [Benedictine abbey at Metten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metten_Abbey). The Germans call it *Benediktussegen*, or Benedict's blessing.

Comment: [There's a separate question about the word *draco*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4337/79) if anyone is wants to learn more about the first note.

Comment: Is *non (draco) sit* a medievalism? Classical usage would be *ne*.

Comment: @TKR I read it roughly as "may something that is not a dragon lead me", but I'm not sure if it's classically sound. A medieval quirk sounds more likely. I smell a good follow-up question...

Comment: @TKR Not classical but not medieval either. [Schultz says](https://books.google.de/books?id=e9ZGAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA306): "Only poets and later prose writers", and quotes Horace (non sileas) and Quintilian (non desperemus).

Comment: Minor quibble: this is a prayer of exorcism, not a blessing :)

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: As Hugh has been proscribed, may I transfer my Q. to yourself, please? The use of "ipse", here: should it be "te (ipsum) venena bibas"?

Comment: @brianpck Interestingly it is called *Benediktussegen* in German, Benedict's blessing. Not sure about exorcism, even if Wikipedia says so. By the way, I wonder if the claim that the text was and still is included in *De Exorcismis et Supplicationibus Quibusdam* is really true; the most recent edition can be found online, I just skimmed it (it's short!) and found nothing.

Comment: @tony The addressee (Satan) is the subject of the sentence (literally: may **you** drink the poisons), so it is: *tu ipse bibas*. If it were *te ipsum*, then he would be the object and someone would drink the devil.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Silly me! When Bear Grylls does his jungle-survival thing and counsels the thirst-crazed explorer to drink his own urine, this would be expressed: "de siti aquae, tuam urinam bibas" = "With a craving for water, you may drink your own urine.". Alternatively: "....te ipsum bibas." = "...., you may drink yourself.". Does that work, probably not?